# SQL : How to sum multiple bit columns in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, type-conversion

I have a data structure that has repeating bit columns per row

[image]

How to I get the total number of Trues for each row? For example

Id   Total
03     2 
17   0 
21   3 
24   2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `bit` to `Int` and do the arithmetic operation

```
select id,cast([Ok_1112] as Int)+cast([Ok_1213] as Int)+...
From yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

For educational purposes here is the version with `UNPIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT, ok1112 bit, ok1213 BIT, ok1314 BIT, ok1415 BIT, ok1516 BIT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(21, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
(24, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

SELECT id, SUM(CAST(a AS int)) AS Total
FROM @t
UNPIVOT(a FOR b IN(ok1112, ok1213, ok1314, ok1415, ok1516))u
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of OK fields, and don't want to code them, try the following

```
Declare @YourTable table (Id int,OK_1112 bit,OK_1213 bit,OK_1314 bit,OK_1415 bit,OK_1516 bit)
Insert into @YourTable values
(3 ,1,1,0,0,0),
(17,0,0,0,0,0),
(21,0,0,1,1,1),
(24,1,1,0,0,0)

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)

Select ID,Total=Sum(cast(Value as int))
 From (
        Select ID    = r.value('@Id','int')
              ,Item  = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
              ,Value = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
         From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="Id"]') as B(attr)
      ) A
 Group By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  Total
3   2
17  0
21  3
24  2
```

FYI if you just run the sub-query, you will see the following

```
ID  Item    Value
3   OK_1112 1
3   OK_1213 1
3   OK_1314 0
3   OK_1415 0
3   OK_1516 0
17  OK_1112 0
17  OK_1213 0
17  OK_1314 0
17  OK_1415 0
17  OK_1516 0
21  OK_1112 0
21  OK_1213 0
21  OK_1314 1
21  OK_1415 1
21  OK_1516 1
24  OK_1112 1
24  OK_1213 1
24  OK_1314 0
24  OK_1415 0
24  OK_1516 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query should give you the required output in MS SQL.

```
select id , (convert (int,OK_1112) + convert (int,OK_1213) + convert (int,OK_1314)+convert (int,OK_1516)) AS total from Table_Name
```

Here, id column is in **int** and columns OK_1112, OK_1213, OK_1314, OK_1516 are of type **bit**.